# Android send mail with attachment from string

Tags: android, string, email, attachment

I have a HTML string which I want to attach to mail as a file. I could save this string to a file and attach it but I want to do it without saving it to a file. I think it should be possible but I don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
String html = "<html><body><b><bold</b><u>underline</u></body></html>";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(html));

// this is where I want to create attachment
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Html.fromHtml(html));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

How can I attach string as a file to mail?

Comment: Attachments are NOT inline contents. By definition, they are files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This code saves you from adding a manifest uses permission to read from external sd card. It creates a temp in files directory on your app private directory then creates the file with the contents of your string and allows read permission so that it can be accessed.

```
String phoneDesc = "content string to send as attachment";

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
        fos = openFileOutput("tempFile", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fos.write(phoneDesc.getBytes(),0,phoneDesc.getBytes().length);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (fos != null)try {fos.close();} catch (IOException ie) {ie.printStackTrace();}
}
File tempFBDataFile  = new File(getFilesDir(),"tempFile");
Intent emailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("someone@somewhere.com"));
emailClient.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Subject";
emailClient.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample mail body content");
emailClient.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(tempFBDataFile));//attachment
Intent emailChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailClient, "select email client");
startActivity(emailChooser);
```

> This should be called whenever you dont need the file anymore.

```
File tempData = new File(getFilesDir(),"tempFile");
if (tempData.exists()) {
    tempData.delete();
}
```

Comment: It says "Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE" is deprecated due to security issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
String pathname= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filename="/MyFiles/mysdfile.txt";
File file=new File(pathname, filename);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
i.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Your email id"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("png/image");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                    "mail--id" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/saved_images/MyImage.png"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

and don't forget to add this below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /
```